# How to expire a wordpress transients

Tags: wordpress, transient

I want to write update query to expire transients . I will upadte their time to 1 in wordpress option table.

I have transients starting by the name `re_compare` and rest after it parameter changes.

My query for update is

```
$wpdb->update( 
    'options', 
    array( 
        'option_value' => '1',  // string

    ), 
    array( 'option_name' => '%re_compare%' )

);
```

Its not working . Basically I want to remove / Expire already existing transients.

But if I delete transients from options table they still show in transient manager plugin. So thought to set their expire time to 1 second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting or modifying transients from options table via plain SQL isn't recommended. Why? Because the database is actually a default fallback location where the transients are stored, not the primary one. If there's any object cache available, transients are stored there, not in the database. So, in your case, it may very well be the case - you're deleting them from options table, but they are actually read from the object cache.

In general, you don't have to worry about expiring transients. WordPress has a garbage collector that purges them automatically.

If the data in transients became stale and you need to update it earlier than it will expire, use the API function for this:

```
delete_transient( 'your_transient_name' );
```

Please also note, that the expiration time is the **maximum** period of time that transient can live. After that period of time, it will never return stored value. However, it may not be available long before the expiration time, due to object cache eviction, database upgrades etc.

So, in short:

- the expiration time is the maximum point in future when the transient call will stop returning the value
- it may be lost long before the expiration time comes, due to other reasons

The rules of thumb for working with transients are:

1. Set your transients with API function
2. Set expiration time to when you absolutely don't want it to be valid anymore
3. Delete it with API function if the data changed on your side (and, most likely, regenerate again)
4. Or just wait for it to expire naturally
5. It will be garbage-collected by WP later
6. Do not expect them to always be available to you until the expiration time comes. They are not guaranteed to persist.

Comment: "In general" perhaps not, but what if, for example, you have to deal with the fallout of a terribly poorly designed wordpress site that uses transients extremely badly combined with an Amazon scraper bot that tried to look at every single page, generating a new transient with each page hit until the mysql binlogs started filling up at a rate of 100 megabytes every two minutes?

Comment: @Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI then you obviously have much bigger problems to solve before you even touch transients.